# Change my name in the list of guests for a specific event in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

How could I change my name in the list of guests for a specific event in Google Calendar?

For example, right now I participate in an event where everyone is marked by name and surname and I am marked by email.

[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvwRr.png).

Answer (score 0):

You can't change how you appear as a guest on someone else's calendar unless you have the access rights to edit the guest list. The host would need to update the guest list by replacing your email with:

`John Doe <jdoe@youremail.com>`

This typically happens if one of the following scenarios holds true:

1. You've never communicated with the host via email and they haven't added you to their contacts.
2. Your email account has not been set up to send your name along with the email. This can typically be remedied by updating your account settings in your email client.